# HTML ContentEdtiable and Child Nodes

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm trying to use the `contentEditable` attribute, however I'm running into some difficulties with child elements.

For example:

```
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <p>some text here</p>
        <p>some longer paragraphs here</p>
        <p>and some more</p>
     </div>
```

I have a `dblclick` which triggers the `contenteditable` to be `true`.  However, I'm finding that I can only click in the very beginning of the text, or the very end, to set the caret.  If I try and click in the middle of the text nothing happens.

It seems maybe that  `contentedtiable` is only applying the `<div>` which is why I can only click the beginning or end to set the caret?

Oddly enough, if I click the end of the text and set the caret, and then use the arrow keys, I can then navigate the caret through the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly! https://jsfiddle.net/pcvwwjoe/
tested in `IE 11` `firefox` and `chrome`

```
<div contenteditable="true">
        <p>some text here</p>
        <p>some longer paragraphs here</p>
        <p>and some more</p>
     </div>
```

Try refreshing your page!

1-works with single click in middle.
2-arrow keys work ect.